# How can I export 16 bit tiffs with Mac OSX' imageing engine sips?

Tags: canon, photo-editing, image-processing, batch, apple

I'm playing around with Apple `sips` command. When I export a Canon raw file (CR2) to tiff via

```
sips -s format tiff -out img.tiff img.cr2
```

the result is an 8-bit tiff, *although* the CR2 source is reported as a 16-bit format.

How can I tell `sips` to export 16-bit tiffs?

ps: I have played with the `--formatOptions` option and with some of the image properties (particularly `bitsPerSample`), but nothing seems to allow for adjustment of the *output* bit depth.

Comment: Does sips actually ever output 16bpp with other formats?  Can you take an LZW tif and convert it to Packbits and retain 16bpp for example?

Comment: @JamesSnell Well, I assume Apple's Aperture uses the same engine as `sips` - and Aperture *can* export 16-bit tiffs.

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the [sips-Manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) there is no way to force exporting of 8 or 16 bit.

That's the answer: there is no way to do this with sips.

Is there any reason for using sips, instead of Lightroom or Aperture, which have great batch modes too?

Comment: Well I wanted to use `sips`, because I guess it is the same engine preview uses to display the images - just for consistency...

Comment: As far as i know, there schoud be no differenz between sips/apature/Lightroom-tiff Images.

Comment: Well, there *is* a difference when you generate the TIFFs from Canon Raw (CR2) files, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: do you can see the differens between an 8 and a 16bit tif? im realy impressed. But your problem was consistency, so if you convert all you pictures to 8 or 16bit tif they will have the same look at ever computer.